# PHP secure root

Tags: php, security, root

My friend found a problem in my script, it gives acces to root files.

This url gives passwd file:

```
http://site.com/attachment.php?file=../../../../../../etc/passwd
```

**How to escape this security hole?**

Comment: *(reference)* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal

Comment: As @Starx pointed out, try to avoid using file paths as identifiers for documents (There are other concerns, beyond directory traversal). (@MartIX' idea about (md5) hashing might help for a lean implementation). Moreover it is a good idea **not to run your server as root**. Use a separate user who has only the rights on the system that are necessary to fulfil its task.

Comment: (That is if you meant that it is possible to access files only readable by the root user, like `/etc/shadow`. `/etc/passwd` is readable by any user in modern Unixes, of course)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several different solutions.
If there can be only a filename, a basename() solution would work.

However, if it can be path, a more complex solution is needed

```
//assume current directory, but can be set anything. Absolute path of course
$basedir   = dirname(__FILE__);
//assume our files are below document root. 
//Otherwise use it's root dir instead of DOCUMENT_ROOT
$filename  = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_GET['file']);
if (substr($filename,0,strlen($basedir)) !== $basedir) {
  header ("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"); 
  exit; 
}
```

there is also a useful PHP configuration option `open_basedir`

Answer (score 14):

Dont download the files using URL String.... Define unique IDs to denote a file, rather than paths.

You might have seen downloads like this `http://www.mysite.com/download.php?id=23423` what they do, use this id, to take out the file name and path from the db and then download it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`realpath()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) and [`dirname()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) to check URLs against [`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) (or whatever directory is "safe" for downloading).

If the result of `realpath()` points outside the safe directory, you can deny the download request.

There's also the [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) security directive (and runtime option as of 5.3).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have a directory where all attachments are stored.

Just test if file is located in your directory.

```
 // http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php
 // http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php 
 if (file_exists($attachments_path . "/" . basename($_GET['file'])) {
  // do work
 }
```

Starx posted a solution which seems fine. It can be done without a database, though. If somebody uploads a file you can store the file as `md5($filename).$extension` and use your script.

Comment: So if there's a file called "passwd" in the attachment directory, the code allows the download of /etc/passwd, too? I'm not a PHP programmer, but I think you should be more explicit in saying that the file to access should be formed in the same manner:

$filename = $attachments_path . "/" . basename($_GET['file'])